# How to write unit test in Android Studio connected with Firebase real time

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to write unit tests in Android Studio to test this method, but I don't know how to write unit tests connected with Firebase. Can anyone help me to write a unit test in Android?

This is my method in `DonatTime` that I want to test. It transfers hours from one user to another and checks if the hours the user entered were equal or less that what the user had.

```
    private void DonateTimeCreditMethod(){
            UserNameD=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameD);
            final String UN=UserNameD.getText().toString().trim();
            NH=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.NH);
            String hour=NH.getText().toString().trim();
            final int Nhour= Integer.parseInt(hour);
            int nhcu,nhsu;

            String CurrentUID=currentuser.getUid().toString();
            DatabaseReference referenceCurU=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(CurrentUID);
            referenceCurU.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshotCU) {
                    final User CUser=dataSnapshotCU.getValue(User.class);
                    final int NHCU= CUser.getTimeCredit();

                    if(NHCU<Nhour){
                        NH.setError("the hour should be less or equal your hours");
                        NH.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }

                    DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
                    Query query=reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(UN);
                    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                UserNameD.setError("wrong username ");
                                UserNameD.requestFocus();
                                return;

                            }else {
                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {



                                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                                    Log.v("Name",user.getName());
                                    user.setTimeCredit(user.getTimeCredit()+Nhour);
                                    snapshot.getRef().setValue(user);
    CUser.setTimeCredit(CUser.getTimeCredit()-Nhour);
                                    dataSnapshotCU.getRef().setValue(CUser);

                                    Toast.makeText(DonateTime.this,"Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent( DonateTime.this, Timeline.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                }
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: A "unit" test *wouldn't* connect to Firebase, it would use some kind of test double to replace Firebase so you can test your code in isolation. If you're testing your code plus its connection to Firebase, that would be an "integration" test.